# Three js loops just in one

Tags: javascript, loops

Hey i just wanted to do one loop which has in three buttons and three drop down lists. But I must created three list because when I connect them connect also drop down lists. My three loops looks like:

```
var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName('list_arrow');
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list_panel');

for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
   arrow[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         list[0].classList.toggle('list_panel_open');
      }
   });
}

for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
   arrow[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         list[2].classList.toggle('list_panel_open');
      }
   });
}

for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
   arrow[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         list[1].classList.toggle('list_panel_open');
      }
   });
}
```

And how can I write this just in one loop?

Comment: Replace arrow[0] and list[0] with arrow[i] and list[i]

Comment: Also please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: unfortunately when I replace with [i] three drop down menus connect just in one and i need three buttoms and three menus

Comment: Or if you use jQuery, just navigate relatively to the list from the button using closest(), parent(), next() etc

Comment: Try to edit your question. I do not understand what you are trying to do. Nether from your question or your code. I assume you have list of arrow elements, and a list of panel elements. And you want to toggle the panel visibility by a click on the arrow?

Comment: Yes, for example, click on first arrow and first drop down menu appear, click on second arrow and second menu appear.

Comment: closure is the best way. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the loop within the loops either:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
   arrow[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      list[i].classList.toggle('list_panel_open'); 
      // since all of the `i` numbers are the same
   });
}
```

Comment: Will this work? I think `i = arrow.length` every time the click event is fired?  Since the function will be run after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should not combine 2 sets of queried elements like that. You are not guaranteed that the index in the array is the same everywhere. Instead set a attribute on the button(`data-id`). In the `onClickElement` handler I get the `data-id` and use it to toggle the target element.

```js
var q = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

function toggleElement(id){
  q("#" + id)[0].classList.toggle('hidden');
}

function onClickElement(){
  var toggleId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
  toggleElement(toggleId);
}

q('.arrow').forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener('click', onClickElement);
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="arrow" data-id="p1">1</button>
<button class="arrow" data-id="p2">2</button>
<button class="arrow" data-id="p3">3</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="p1" class="panel hidden">Panel 1</div>
<div id="p2" class="panel hidden">Panel 2</div>
<div id="p3" class="panel hidden">Panel 3</div>
```